# Why does this generator function break?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, generator

I'm playing around with ES6 Generators, because they've been quite the hype recently. My goal is to have a generator which yields a subset of a larger generator and stops. However, when the generator is called again, instead of repeating the sequence, it continues. Much like an ES6 Generator. In other words, I have a nested generator.

```
const a = function* (): Generator<number> {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        yield i;

    for (const i of a())
        yield i;
}

const b = function* (gen: Generator<number>, subsetSize: number): Generator<number> {
    let i = 0;
    for (const j of gen) {
        if (i++ > subsetSize)
            return;
        else
            yield j;
    }
    console.log("Done");
}

const gen = a();

for (let i = 0; i < 150; i++)
    for (const j of b(gen, 10))
        console.log(j);
```

What I'm expecting this code to do is print the numbers 0-10, print `Done`, then print 10-20, print `Done` and so on. However, the actual output is 0-10 then `Done` repeatedly. I'm not sure why, nor how I would get the result I'm looking for.

Comment: `a` calls `a` -- is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, this is intentional. the goal of `a` is to repeat forever.

Comment: If you want `a()` to repeat forever, why not code a simple unbounded `while()` loop around the first `for` loop? As it is, you have to deal with the fact that the recursive calls to `a()` will *also* recurse.

Comment: I had tried this before, and it caused the process to loop forever, unproductively. 
I've just put this into the code, and get the same results as mentioned in the question.

Comment: I would suggest adding a "level" parameter to `a()` so that you can add trace log statements that illustrate what's going on at various key points in the code. If you're playing with generators as a learning exercise, that'll be much more illuminating than simply getting an answer.

Comment: understood. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the `return` in the `for (const j of gen) {` of `b`, and the fact that you have `for (const j of b(gen, 10))` called in a loop.

When you `return` out of a `for-of` loop, it calls the [`return` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/return) of the generator being iterated (`gen` in this case, the one from `a`). That finishes the generator, so all subsequent attempts to use that generator (because the calls to `b` reuse `gen` and those calls are in a loop) just keep returning that same value. (`break` from the loop will also call `return` on the generator.)

Here's a simpler example:

```js
function* example() {
    let i = 0;
    while (true) {
        yield i++;
    }
}

function use(gen) {
    let counter = 0;
    console.log("Starting for-of on gen");
    for (const value of gen) {
        console.log(value);
        if (value > 5) {
            console.log("Returning early");
            return;
        }
    }
    console.log("Done with for-of on gen");
}

const gen = example();
use(gen);
use(gen);
use(gen);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If you don't want that automatic behavior of `for-of`, you might call `next` on the generator directly rather than using `for-of`. (If you want `0-9`, `"Done"`, `10-19`, `"Done"`, etc, you also have to tweak your counter and move where you're outputting `"Done"`.) Example:

```js
const a = function* ()/*: Generator<number>*/ {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        yield i;

    for (const i of a())
        yield i;
}

const b = function* (gen/*: Generator<number>*/, subsetSize/*: number*/)/*: Generator<number>*/ {
    let i = 0;
    let result;
    while (!(result = gen.next()).done) {
        yield result.value;
        if (++i >= subsetSize) {
            console.log("Done");
            return;
        }
    }
}

const gen = a();

for (let i = 0; i < /*150*/3; i++)
    for (const j of b(gen, 10))
        console.log(j);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Alternatively, you could wrap the generator in an object that only forwarded `next` calls (and implemented `[Symbol.iterator]`):

```
const continuingIterator = it => {
    return {
        [Symbol.iterator]() {
            return this;
        },
        next() {
            return it.next();
        },
    };
};
```

Then it would be:

```
for (const j of continuingIterator(gen)) {
```

Live Example:

```js
const continuingIterator = it => {
    return {
        [Symbol.iterator]() {
            return this;
        },
        next() {
            return it.next();
        },
    };
};

const a = function* ()/*: Generator<number>*/ {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        yield i;

    for (const i of a())
        yield i;
}

const b = function* (gen/*: Generator<number>*/, subsetSize/*: number*/)/*: Generator<number>*/ {
    let i = 0;
    for (const j of continuingIterator(gen)) {
        yield j;
        if (++i >= subsetSize) {
            console.log("Done");
            return;
        }
    }
}

const gen = a();

for (let i = 0; i < /*150*/3; i++)
    for (const j of b(gen, 10))
        console.log(j);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for some way to use the `for-of` loops, as they're much cleaner. I tried using `break` statements instead, but that didn't work. As per your advice, the `next()` solution stands! Thanks for your help

Comment: @JacobSchneider - You're welcome! `for-of` is definitely designed for the use case where you're going to be 'done" with the iterator/generator when you terminate the loop. You *could* use `for-of` by wrapping the generator in another object and only forwarding `next` calls... :-D

Comment: That would be an interesting approach. I'll definitely look into it

Comment: @JacobSchneider - I couldn't help myself, see the updated answer. :-D Happy coding!

Comment: Oh my, that's fantastic! I did end up experimenting with that method and it actually works quite well. I'll be using that method from now on.

Comment: T.J. you should coin a term for this, the word "immunization" comes to mind given the zeitgeist